# Trying to display text on image button

Tags: ios

I am trying to display text on button,but nothing display.

```
 LocationButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

 UIImage * Location_buttonImages = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button~iphone.png"];

 [LocationButton setTitle:@"Loca" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [LocationButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [LocationButton setImage:Location_buttonImages forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [LocationButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
 @"button_select~iphone.png"]  
 forState:UIControlStateSelected];

  LocationButton.frame =  CGRectMake(20,212,90,40);

 [LocationButton addTarget:self action:
 @selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  [self.view addSubview:LocationButton];
```

I can see the image but no text visible.Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [LocationButton setImage:Location_buttonImages forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [LocationButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_select~iphone.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

You overlay image on Title, so that no title display. Change to setBackgroundImage:forState

```
 [LocationButton setBackgroundImage:Location_buttonImages forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [LocationButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_select~iphone.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```